# Can I alter a BQ destination table from Datastream for better performance?

Tags: google-bigquery, data-partitioning, change-data-capture, google-datastream

I'm working with a Stream job from an Oracle database to Biguery using Datastream, and some of the tables are transactional so I'm wondering if I can alter some of them (created automatically by Datastream) to add partition and/or clustering, to improve performance and reduce billing. I know Bigquery doesn't let me add a partition to an existing table, but can I recreate it (with the partition + clustering) and then let the Stream to use the table?